# iphone: UITABLEView crashing the application

Tags: iphone, uitableview, sqlite

dont know whats wrong with my table view, I have a dictionary(this dictionary is created by a sqlite operation) and I am trying to create cells like this

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"MyIdentifier";
MyIdentifier = @"tblCellView";

CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
if(cell == nil) {
    [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell" owner:self options:nil];
    cell = aCustomCell;
    aCustomCell=nil;
}

NSMutableDictionary *tempDictionary=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

tempDictionary=[offendersNamesList objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"key%d", indexPath.row+1]];

[[cell offendersImageView] setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"contact.png"]];
[cell.offendersNameLbl setText:[tempDictionary objectForKey:@"name"]];
[cell.offendersViolation setText:[tempDictionary objectForKey:@"offence"]];
[tempDictionary release];

//[cell setLabelText:[arryData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
return cell;
```

}

all the items are displayed correctly but when I scroll the table view up the application crashes can you help me in this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are first allocating a new NSMutableDictionary and store it in `tempDictionary`. However, in the very next line, you overwrite that variable with a pointer to a new object (`tempDictionary=[offendersNamesList objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"key%d", indexPath.row+1]];`). So you've got a memory leak here, the `[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init]` is unnecessary, remove it.

Now, due to the naming conventions, the object that you've got from the `offendersNamesList` is autoreleased, yet you later call `[tempDictionary release];` and thus over-release it. Remove that as well.